# Add Css style to edited cell in slickgrid

Tags: styling, slickgrid

I'm just a beginner and I couldn't figure it out how to add a css class to edited cell in slickgrid. I've searched and didn't get the answer.

- [SlickGrid styling after cell edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197784)
- [Assigning CSS Style to Slickgrid Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591745)

I've got these steps to do:

- store in a variable the edited by using grid.onCellChange event
- add css style using grid.setCssCellStyles or grid.addCellCssStyle.
  (or) by building a custom formatter.

Could somebody provide the sample code for this?

Comment: I've solve the problem using grid.setCellCssStyles from https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/API-Reference. But how can I change the value of 0 into dynamically loading? Can I use args.row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented this exactly as suggested in the first referenced link.  The second argument passed to SlickGrid.setCellCssStyles() is a hash keyed by row numbers, with the value being another hash keyed by column id and its value being the css class.

The code as follows:

```css
<style type="text/css">
    .slick-cell-modified {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
```

```js
<script>
    var modifiedCells = {};
    grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e, args) {
        if (!modifiedCells[args.row]) {
            modifiedCells[args.row] = {};
        }
        modifiedCells[args.row][this.getColumns()[args.cell].id] = "slick-cell-modified";
        this.setCellCssStyles("modified", modifiedCells);
        // ...update data view
    });
</script>
```

Be sure to clear the cell css style after saving so the highlighted style don't stick around.

```js
function saveChanges() {
    // ...
    grid.removeCellCssStyles("modified");
    modifiedCells = {};
}
```